# How to only show custom php field if there is a value

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm new to php and currently working with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for wordpress. I currently have this bit of php code:

```
<?php

$group_ID = 110;

$fields = array();
$fields = apply_filters('acf/field_group/get_fields', $fields, $group_ID);

if ($fields) {
    echo '<div class="promotion-area">';
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $value = get_field($field['name']);
        echo '<div>' . $value . '</div>';

    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

I'm am trying to attempt to show `<div class="promotion-area">` only if there are values to view and remove the div if no values are available.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a var_dump:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(18) { ["key"]=> string(19) "field_55bae192c069d" ["label"]=> string(15) "Promotion Title" ["name"]=> string(15) "promotion_title" ["_name"]=> string(15) "promotion_title" ["type"]=> string(4) "text" ["order_no"]=> int(0) ["instructions"]=> string(0) "" ["required"]=> int(0) ["id"]=> string(25) "acf-field-promotion_title" ["class"]=> string(4) "text" ["conditional_logic"]=> array(3) { ["status"]=> int(0) ["rules"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["field"]=> string(4) "null" ["operator"]=> string(2) "==" ["value"]=> string(0) "" } } ["allorany"]=> string(3) "all" } ["default_value"]=> string(0) "" ["placeholder"]=> string(0) "" ["prepend"]=> string(0) "" ["append"]=> string(0) "" ["formatting"]=> string(4) "html" ["maxlength"]=> string(0) "" ["field_group"]=> int(110) } [1]=> array(17) { ["key"]=> string(19) "field_55bae1d7c069f" ["label"]=> string(17) "Promotion Content" ["name"]=> string(17) "promotion_content" ["_name"]=> string(17) "promotion_content" ["type"]=> string(8) "textarea" ["order_no"]=> int(1) ["instructions"]=> string(0) "" ["required"]=> int(0) ["id"]=> string(27) "acf-field-promotion_content" ["class"]=> string(8) "textarea" ["conditional_logic"]=> array(3) { ["status"]=> int(0) ["rules"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["field"]=> string(4) "null" ["operator"]=> string(2) "==" ["value"]=> string(0) "" } } ["allorany"]=> string(3) "all" } ["default_value"]=> string(0) "" ["placeholder"]=> string(0) "" ["maxlength"]=> string(0) "" ["rows"]=> int(4) ["formatting"]=> string(2) "br" ["field_group"]=> int(110) } }
```

Comment: if( isset( $fields ) && is_array( $fields ) && !empty( $fields ) ){ /* show the stuff */ }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if there is something in your variable use `empty()` language construction ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)) with `is_array()` method to make sure that your variable is an array ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)):

```
if (is_array($fields) && !empty($fields)) {
    // do something if var $fields is not empty
}
```

---

Looking at your result array which is not empty and it always pass above conditions, you need to `foreach` twice to check if there is your value and then display it.

```
if (!empty($fields)) {
    $values = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $value = get_field($field['name']);
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $values[] = $value;
        }
    }
    if (!empty($values)) {
        echo '<div class="promotion-area">';
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            echo '<div>' . $value . '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and while it doesn't show the values it still shows the div class.

Comment: @pedz Could you post here a `var_dump($fields)` of `$fields` variable?

Comment: Just posed a var dump in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `$fields` holds any data by doing

```
if (count($fields) > 0) {
   ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code. Try this

```
<?php
  $group_ID = 110;

   $fields = array();
   $fields = apply_filters('acf/field_group/get_fields', $fields, $group_ID);

  if (!empty($fields)) {          
   foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $value[] = get_field($field['name']);        
   }         
 }
 if(!empty($value)) {
  echo '<div class="promotion-area">'; 
  foreach ($value as $result) {
    $new_value = $result;
    echo '<div>' . $new_value . '</div>';
  }            
  echo '</div>';
 }  
?>
```

Comment: While this removes the inner divs around the value it still doesn't remove the <div class="promotion-area">. Should I be moving that class elsewhere?

Comment: I have edited the code to display based on $value. Let me know if this is what you need?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work but I received my answer already. Thanks for trying to help.